# What are the cyber warfare capabilities of Iran's Revolutionary Guard?

Tags: armed-conflict, iran, middle-east, cyber-warfare

In 2013, officials in Israeli claimed that the Revolutionary Guard of Iran was the [fourth biggest cyber power when it came to cyber warfare](https://www.hackread.com/iran-biggest-cyber-army-israel/). What are the cyber-warfare capabilities of the Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps in Iran and how do they compare to other nations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a programmer, interested in, but not specialized in, security and often listen to the Risky Business podcast which brings in 2 security professionals as well as a journalist who's been covering the subject for 15 years.

Coincidentally, [a recent podcast](https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/risky-business/risky-business-567-totok-exWGz3ICgtX/) was covering the post-Suleimani news and opined specifically on this subject - the coverage about Iranian cyber starts at about 2:00 minute mark.

Their take:  the Guards are quite competent.  Not necessarily at the top of nation states wrt to crafting exploit tools and and having the latest and greatest software or hardware.  But they do have good stuff, know how to use it and are strong in using social engineering to enhance their capabilities.

So, worthy opponent, even if the same podcast has over the last few months noted cases where their hacker crews suffered aggressive cyber-attacks (things like their servers getting wiped out).